# Xamarin Android C# Video resizing

Tags: c#, android, video, xamarin

I need to send a video to the server.
Video sizes differ randomly, some can be a Meg and others can be 900Mb..
How does one resize a video to a smaller size?

I can get iOS examples but have not found any Android versions.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, first thing i searched https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54461/resizing-and-converting-a-video

Answer (score 4):

A lot of it depends upon what you mean by **making it smaller**:

- Trimming the length (running time) of the video
- Changing the playback rate (FPS)
- Resizing to a smaller resolution
- Changing the bitrate to a lower one
- Re-compressing/transcoding the video using a different codec or the same codec but using a higher compression ratio.

Android's MediaCodec library can change a number of things, but does not give the user a lot of options on "how" it does it:

- Resolutions 1080P, 720P, 480P, 360P, QVGA, QCIF
- BitRates  2Mbps, 1Mbps, 500Kbps, 56Kbps
- FrameRates = 30fps. 15fps
- FrameIntervals = 1, 5, 10

(that is just a quick sampling of MediaCodec's ability)

#### MediaCodec Usage:

> The way you use the Android MediaCodec for "transcoding" is use the Decoder to process the original video (off screen), pass those frames to the Encoder (using different encoding options then the original) and save the results to file...

The *most popular* method for video resizing/transcoding/etc... on Android seems to be using `ffmpeg` due to the large number of options available and how well known that application is.

There Java wrappers (and a couple of C# wrappers) available for Android, I have only used the Java based ones via a Binding project. (Google is your friend for finding these).

There is a bunch of licensing "issues" in using FFmpeg and you should review their license:

[FFmpeg License and Legal Considerations](http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html)

Comment: Was hoping on a resize.. but think that if the video is to big then maybe I should see if I can at least take a snippet from it or something..

Comment: Android's MediaCodec can resize videos (along with a bunch of other things). i.e.e It can change videos to 1080P, 720P, 480P, 360P,QVGA, QCIF... Again it really depends upon you need from original video

Comment: Thank you will have a good proper look into the media codec :)

Comment: @Migz: This is `Java` based but a good source to see how it all works, I have use it in a custom C# binding library but it could be rewritten in C# https://github.com/hoolrory/AndroidVideoSamples/blob/71d2c49bd7dc7ae2cd5169a600fe7577ea8c4d77/CommonVideoLibrary/src/com/roryhool/commonvideolibrary/VideoResampler.java